# Render the UI on observing the LiveData value

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-livedata, coroutine

I am rendering the UI of **Fragment** on observing the **LiveData** value, **LiveData** variable is modifying based on the Value in **Room**. I am facing the small delay while rendering the UI due to reading the the value from Room(Dispacter.IO) so, after that updating liveData value and when LiveData value will change on observer update the UI. This process taking time. Any way to reduce it?

Comment: How much delay are you getting? what are you trying to display? A complex list?

Comment: Not complex list its just the simple UI with Image, text and buttons and getting the delay of 500ms approx.. which user can see. Actually UI rendering happens in Fragment and Activity also have it own UI. So when Delay happens Activity UI change to Fragment UI which is noticeable by User.

Comment: that shouldn't happen. Half second is very much just to show this small amount of data. try to do it without the live data and see if this still happens

Comment: @Someshkumar I want to use Live data... as per PR request there is any other way...

Comment: Seems like this Room delay is here to stay. I am also facing this issue and coming from in memory storage this experience feels really bad.